# Как запустить две задачи с помощью asyncio

Tags: python, async-await

Есть функция которая читает сообщения в чате, и которая принимает параметр с айди чата:

```
import somelib

client = somelib.Client()

client.login(email="email", password="password")
subclient = somelib.SubClient(comId="comId", profile=client.profile)
botname = subclient.get_user_info(userId=client.userId).nickname

old = []


class Bot:

    async def run(self, chatid):
        while True:
            msg = subclient.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=2)
            for message, author, messageId in zip(msg.content, msg.author.nickname, msg.messageId):
                if messageId in old:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"{author} : {message}")
                    if author != botname:
                        if message[0] == "!":
                            if message.lower() == "!ping":
                                subclient.send_message(chatId=chatid, message="Pong!")
                    old.append(messageId)
```

В файле `main.py` я попробовал запустить 2 задачи, которые читали бы 2 разных чата асинхронно

```
import asyncio

from lib.bot import Bot

bot = Bot()


async def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("START")
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(bot.run('881beb78-2a54-0391-2cee-94c8dfc0ce3d'))
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(bot.run('a5dd10aa-551d-41b9-95f6-96fd3bf087dc'))
        await task1
        await task2

asyncio.run(main())
```

Но бот читает сообщения только с первого чата (`task1`), второй он игнорирует. Как сделать что бы две задачи работали одновременно ? Или как можно заставить бота читать два чата одновременно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функции `main` все сделано правильно. Корутины действительно должны выполняться параллельно.

Но в корутинах нет ни одного await. Именно в этих точках управление отдается циклу событий (event-loop) и он решает, какую корутину выполнить сейчас, так происходит переключение между выполнением разных корутин. Но функция блокирует event-loop и сначала выполняется полностью первый вызов, затем второй. Но первый вызов - бесконечный цикл. До второго вызова дело никогда не дойдет.

Как тут быть? У меня вопросы к функциям `get_chat_messages` и `send_message`, судя по их названию - блокирующие. Поэтому должны быть асинхронные и вызваны с `await`, т.е. `some_lib` должна быть с поддержкой асинхронности.

Как обстоит дело:

- вызвали `get_chat_messages`
- получили список сообщений
- обработали его, откинув уже обработанные
- снова `get_chat_messages` и до бесконечности...

Второй чат не у дел, переключиться на него негде.

Если переписать код клиентов, добавив туда поддержку асинхронности (или использовать другой), и добавить `await` здесь

```
msg = await subclient.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=2)
```

и здесь

```
await subclient.send_message(chatId=chatid, message="Pong!")
```

То все должно сработать. Пока один чат получает список сообщений или занят отправкой сообщения, второй может провести свою работу и вернуть управление назад, когда сам начнет получать список сообщений или отправлять сообщение.

Comment: https://github.com/Slimakoi/Amino.py/blob/master/amino/sub_client.py Возможно ли добавить сюда поддержку асинхронности?

Comment: Лично я бы никогда не взялся. Я вижу только один выход - начать переписывать свой код и тут есть 2 пути: найти другую библиотеку с готовой асинхронностью и интегрировать ее; либо забыть про asyncio и переписать свой код под старые добрые потоки https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently), вы можете использовать `asyncio.gather()`:

```
async def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("START")
        await asyncio.gather(bot.run('881beb78-2a54-0391-2cee-94c8dfc0ce3d'),
                             bot.run('a5dd10aa-551d-41b9-95f6-96fd3bf087dc'),)
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: К сожалению, не поможет. `gather` под капотом использует `create_task` и собирает результаты в удобном виде. Это просто обертка.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за разъяснения